# Probabilistic Programming in Scala

Tags: scala, probability

Can anyone advise on the use of a probabilistic programming library? I've looked at the following:

- https://github.com/jliszka/probability-monad which seems reasonably up to date but is based on just one huge module and has some stylistic aspects which I'm not entirely comfortable with;
- https://github.com/sstucki/odds which seems to be more "pure" and "functional" but hasn't been worked on for about two years (I'm also curious where they get their definition of Rand from);

Is there anything else that I should look at? I'm particularly interested in being able to determine the probability that two distributions can be considered to overlap (for the purpose of creating an algebra for fuzzy quantities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [Figaro](https://www.cra.com/work/case-studies/figaro). This was developed by Avi Pfeffer who, I believe, was the first to point out that a probability distribution (or a sampler for a probability distribution) can be viewed as monad with flatMap/bind corresponding to marginalization. He's also working on a [book on the topic of probabilistic programming](https://www.manning.com/books/practical-probabilistic-programming) to be published by Manning.

> I'm particularly interested in being able to determine the probability that two distributions can be considered to overlap (for the purpose of creating an algebra for fuzzy quantities).

I'm not quite sure what you mean here. If you can clarify this a bit, I might be able to offer additional suggestions.

Comment: As far as my fuzzy quantities comment is concerned, I have previously built fuzzy quantity frameworks in Java and would really like to create a much better one in Scala. For me, a fuzzy quantity is one where I can compare two quantities a and b with the result that a==b has P(a=b) and a>b has P(a>b), etc. For example, let's say I calculate sin(pi/2) and compare it with 1. Using normal arithmetic, I would have to subtract the difference, take the absolute value and compare that with an arbitrary epsilon value. Not very cool.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a== b has P(a=b)".

Comment: What I meant (I hoped it was clear but it wasn't): comparing two quantities, there are three outcomes: a<b, a=b, a>b. For integers, these all have clear truth values (only one can be true). But for fuzzy quantities, each of these can be considered to have a probability (summing to 1).